# This powershell doesnt give item count to all the sub or sub-sub or sub-sub-sub folders

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, count

I am trying to get a count of each folders in a document library. There are many folders under the parent. Each folder may have few more folders and each one of this may have child, grand child folders.

I can add lot more coding but I have a feeling it could be done better way. Please suggest.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://inside.cnv.uk/sales/SouthWest"
$list = $web.Lists["SalesManJR"]
$folders = $list.RootFolder.Subfolders
foreach ($folder in $folders)
{ 
    if (!$folder.Name.Equals("Forms"))
    {       
        write-host "Folder Name: " $folder.Name  " Count: "  $folder.Files.Count
        $subfolderURL = $list.RootFolder.SubFolders[$list.Title+"/"+$folder.Name]
        $subfolders = $subfolderURL.SubFolders
        foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders)
        {
            write-host "  Sub-Folder Name: " $subfolder.Name " Count: " $subfolder.Files.Count      
        }       
    }
}
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code works.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://inside.cnv.uk/sales/SouthWest"
# $list name is list display name
$list = $web.Lists["SalesManJR"]
$folders = $list.RootFolder.Subfolders

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{ 
    if (!$folder.Name.Equals("Forms"))
    {       
        write-host ""
        write-host "Folder Name: " $folder.Name  " Count: "  $folder.Files.Count
        $subfolderURL = $list.RootFolder.SubFolders[$list.Title+"/"+$folder.Name]
        $subfolders = $subfolderURL.SubFolders
        foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders)
        {
            write-host " Folder Name: " $subfolder.Name " Count: " $subfolder.ItemCount     
            #write-host "  Sub-Folder Name: " $subfolder.Name " Count: " $subfolder.Files.Count     

            # Sub Folder Level 2            
            $subfolders2 = $subfolder.SubFolders
            foreach ($subfolder2 in $subfolders2)
            {
                write-host "  Folder Name: " $subfolder2.Name " Count: " $subfolder2.ItemCount      
                #write-host "  Sub-Folder Name: " $subfolder.Name " Count: " $subfolder.Files.Count

                # Sub Folder Level 3            
                $subfolders3 = $subfolder2.SubFolders
                foreach ($subfolder3 in $subfolders3)
                {
                    write-host "  Folder Name: " $subfolder3.Name " Count: " $subfolder3.ItemCount

                    # Sub Folder Level 4            
                    $subfolders4 = $subfolder3.SubFolders
                    foreach ($subfolder4 in $subfolders4)
                    {
                        write-host "    Folder Name: " $subfolder4.Name " Count: " $subfolder4.ItemCount                    
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}

$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you'll want to use a recursive function. I don't know about your folder structure, but something like this should do it:

```
function Process-Folder($Folder)
{
    Write-Host "Folder Name: " $folder.Name  " Count: "  $folder.Files.Count
    $subFolders = #Do something to get the subfolders#
    if ($subFolders -ne $null)
    {
        foreach ($subFolder in $subFolders)
        {
            Process-Folder $subFolder
        }
    }
}

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://inside.cnv.uk/sales/SouthWest"
$list = $web.Lists["SalesManJR"]
$folders = $list.RootFolder.Subfolders
foreach ($folder in $folders)
{ 
    if (!$folder.Name.Equals("Forms"))
    {
        Process-Folder $folder
    }
}
```

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92622/how-to-iterate-through-all-folders-inside-subfolders-of-root-level-folders does not work. item count only on parent folders are zero.

Comment: "Do something to get the subfolders."  Do WHAT to get the subfolders?????